Why doesn't relativize work for jar resources?
I want to get the path of a jar resource relative to the jar root. This is the MVCE I created:
// Using website example to demonstrate relativize working
URL website = new URL("https://stackoverflow.com/");
URL webpage = new URL("https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer");
URI webRelative = website.toURI().relativize(webpage.toURI());

URL jarUrl = new URL("file:/C:/Users/cardinal/Desktop/Test.jar");
URL jarRootUrl = new URL("jar:file:/C:/Users/cardinal/Desktop/Test.jar!/");
URL resourceUrl = new URL("jar:file:/C:/Users/cardinal/Desktop/Test.jar!/mydir/myresource.txt");

// Here relativize is not working (or perhaps it is working, just not the way I am expecting)
URI jarRelative1 = jarUrl.toURI().relativize(resourceUrl.toURI());
URI jarRelative2 = jarRootUrl.toURI().relativize(resourceUrl.toURI());

System.out.println(webRelative);
System.out.println(jarRelative1);
System.out.println(jarRelative2);

The output is as follows:
help/how-to-answer
jar:file:/C:/Users/cardinal/Desktop/Test.jar!/mydir/myresource.txt
jar:file:/C:/Users/cardinal/Desktop/Test.jar!/mydir/myresource.txt

But I am expecting it to be similar to:
help/how-to-answer
/mydir/myresource.txt
mydir/myresource.txt

Why doesn't relativize work for jar resources?

Looking at the URI source relativise doesn't do anything if either URI is "opaque" - isOpaque returns true on those URIs.

or from the documentation: "If either this URI or the given URI are opaque, or ..., then the given URI is returned."

Even if relativize would work with jarRootUrl and resourceUrl, it should never work with jarUrl and resourceUrl because they have different schemes.
